# c ++ Data entry and read back to array in struct structure in list

Tags: c++, list, arraylist, struct, linked-list

I'd like to simply ask you about something i can't solve in the algorithm I'm designing.
I'm asking a question that's purely learning.
I searched both stackoverflow and Uncle Google, but I didn't see a logical solution.

```
 struct MyStruct_1
{
    int number[];
};
```

Imagine it's such a struct Or imagine that there are a few other things in it that aren't arrays.

```
 struct MyStruct_2
{
    int  id;
    string ModelName;
    int number[];
};

**Insert ==>>>  ID = 1 ModelName = "ModelA" number = { 6,7,8,9, 57 }
Insert ==>>>  ID = 2 ModelName = "ModelB" number = { 3,17,9,28,8 }
*****************************************************************
Update/Delete ==>>>  ID = 2 ModelName = "ModelB" number = { 9 }
Update/Delete ==>>>  ID = 1 ModelName = "ModelA" number = { 57 }
*****************************************************************
Insert/Add ==>>>   ID = ModelName = "ModelA" number = 103**
```

In this way, from a structure to a C++ language;

```
list<MyStruct> demoListe
```

when I create

**My 1st question:** how do we provide data entry?
push_back ({ 9,3,65,2 }); I tried it, but I got an error message.

**My 2nd question:** Can the friend who answers the data to enter the data also sample reading the data?

> **I'd like to thank everyone who will help and lead me to the right solution.**
>
> **Regards**

Comment: @TedLyngmo   What is a viable solution to overcoming prohibitions or complying with prohibitions?

Comment: What is a viable solution to overcoming prohibitions or complying with prohibitions?

Comment: I put that in the first sentence of my answer below :-) Use a `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexible arrays are forbidden in standard C++. You should use a `std::vector` instead:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct MyStruct
{
    int id;
    std::string ModelName;
    std::vector<int> number;
};

int main() {
    // initialized with a few numbers
    MyStruct ms{1, "model", {2,3,4}};

    // push_back a new number
    ms.number.push_back(5);

    // print the numbers
    for(int value : ms.number) {
        std::cout << value << '\n';
    }

    // or make a std::list<MyStruct>
    std::list<MyStruct> demoListe {
        {1, "model_a", {2,3,4}},
        {2, "model_b", {5,6,7,8}}
    };

    // add a model
    demoListe.emplace_back(MyStruct{3, "model_c", {11,22}});

    // add 99 to model_a
    auto ait = std::find_if(demoListe.begin(), demoListe.end(), 
                            [](const MyStruct& ms) { return ms.id==1;} );
    if(ait != demoListe.end())
        ait->number.push_back(99);

    // remove 7 from model_b
    auto bit = std::find_if(demoListe.begin(), demoListe.end(),
                            [](const MyStruct& ms) { return ms.id==2;} );
    if(bit != demoListe.end()) {
        auto seven = std::find(bit->number.begin(), bit->number.end(), 7);
        if(seven != bit->number.end())
            bit->number.erase(seven);
    }

    // print result
    for(const MyStruct& ms : demoListe) {
        std::cout << "id: " << ms.id << " model: " << ms.ModelName << '\n';
        std::copy(ms.number.begin(), ms.number.end(),
                  std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

What I don't understand is ms.number.push_back(5); 
        {1, "model_a", {2,3,4}},
        {2, "model_b", {5,6,7,8}}

If I wanted to add 99 to the "model a" which is ID = 1 here, and at the same time 
What if I want to delete 7 from "model b" which is ID = 2?

How does it work?

Comment: Lyngmo      I updated by adding the example I wanted to ask   . Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm trying it right now. I didn't update the page when I wrote it

Comment: I've tried what you've written, thank you very much.
But if I wanted to add a new model, there was a problem.

demoListe.insert (3, "Model_C", { 31,32,33,34,35 });  

I couldn't log in like this, do I have to use a different method?

Comment: @UmitTerzi [std::list::insert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/insert) requires an iterator and it inserts the value before that iterator. Look at the `emplace_back` example in my answer how to add one `MyStruct` to the end of the list.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/cQ9jpH    ............ Thank you so much for everything. I'm going to learn and improve by studying the code you've written in detail.

Answer (score 2):

Note that this code is OK:

```cpp
struct st
{
   int id;
   string s;
};

vector<st> v;

v.push_back({1, "abc"});
```

But you can't initialize array with `{}`, So use Vector Container:

```cpp
struct st
{
   int id;
   string s;
   vector<int> v;
};

vector<st> u;

u.push_back({1, "abc", vector<int>{1, 1, 2}});
```

Comment: Can't vector be a solution using just STRUCT and LIST without using it? 
      Thank you very much for the reply

Comment: @UmitTerzi Do you mean not to use vector? Of course. Just replace every `vector` with a `list`.

Comment: Yes, I meant not to use Vector.
But without knowing the job, I ask, what do you think is better in terms of performance, which is the solution to do it using lists instead of vector?

Comment: @UmitTerzi Which one to choose depends on the use-case. For most use-cases, `std::vector` is preferred.

Comment: @UmitTerzi It depends. Vectors are different from lists. Different works, different capabilities, and different usages. You can see cplusplus.com, Or ask a new question to get more info.